# Типографія чи типографіка?

Tags: терміни, росіянізм, вибір-слова

Бачу що зараз в українській мові є два терміни, яки описують друкарське мистецтво оформлення книги. Вікіпедія підтримує слово "типографія":

> **Типографія** (грец. τύπογραφία, рос.  типографика) — мистецтво оздоблення друкарського тексту. Включає в себе мистецтва шрифтового дизайну, шрифтового оздоблення, верстки.
>
> До питань типографії відносять також прийняті для певної мови традиції використання розділових та службових знаків, розмір проміжка, прийнятну частоту переносів тощо.

Так само цей термін підтримує дописувач на [ua_mova](http://ua-mova.livejournal.com/424098.html), мотивуючи це тим що розрізнення типографії і типографіки важливе для росіян, а в українській мові є слово друкарня, а отже типографія — слово "вільне" і може взяти на себе смисл "друкарський дизайн".

З іншого боку термін **типографіка** вживає [onlinecorrector.com.ua](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/), Кафедра дизайну ХНТУ називає так [учбову дисципліну](http://kntu.net.ua/index.php/kaf_design/Kafedra-Dizajn/Galereya/Pereglyadi-disciplini/SHrifti-ta-Tipografika/SHrifti-ta-tipografika-1-kurs).

Чи є якесь остаточне вирішення цього питання — яке слово правильно вживати в цьому смислі - типографія чи типографіка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Інші обговорення:

- Type.org.ua (сайт не працює), [допис у UA_MOVA](http://ua-mova.livejournal.com/424098.html), [журнал T-magazine](//issuu.com/t-magazine/docs/t-magazine1) (ст. 4).
- [Обговорення у Вікіпедії](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F:%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%8F).

#### Моя особиста думка

Факт № 1. Навіть у цих самих обговореннях не заперечують, що слово «типографіка» (чи правомірно, чи як недоречна калька із нормативного російського слова, чи як калька з російського слова, що недоречне навіть у російській мові) доволі поширилося.

Факт № 2. Я не бачу, від чого в даному випадку захищати українську мову. Обидва слова мають не українське (і не російське; а грецьке) походження. Обидва утворені традиційно для українського словотвору. **Слово «типографіка» має гіперонім «графіка»**, що має бути знайомим кожному українцю з часів навчання у школі.

> Графіка — розділ на­уки про мову, який вивчає сукупність умовних зна­ків для передачі на письмі усного мовлення. [[1]](http://ukrajinskamova.org.ua/hrafika/) [[2]](http://www.ridnamova.kiev.ua/html/2.html) [[3]](http://esu.com.ua/search_articles.php?id=26852) [[4]](//ukr.ed-era.com/1/fonetika_grafka_orfoepya.html) [[5]](http://linguana.com.ua/ukrayinska-mova/grafika/grafika-pysmo.html) [[6]](http://pidruchniki.com/1211120148088/dokumentoznavstvo/grafika) [[7]](//books.google.com/books?id=JpekBQAAQBAJq=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) [[8]](http://pravila-uk-mova.com.ua/index/movoznavstvo/0-4) [[9]](//books.google.com/books?id=Zi5vqGIV6tIC&q=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) (Тобто як писати самі знаки; а як комбінувати їх у слова — то вже питання орфографії.)

Відповідно слово «*типо*графіка» (<sub>грецьк.</sub> τύπος «відбиток»), як на мене, виглядає цілком логічним для звуженої дисципліни, що вивчає не зображення знаків у цілому, а нюанси їх зображення саме при поширеному нині друкарському способі відтворення, — навіть якби такого слова не було в російській мові.

Разом з тим, я не заперечую права на застовування слова «тифографія» — в обох значеннях: і як [друкарня](//books.google.com/books?id=h3hQAAAAYAAJ&q=%22%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%97%22), і як дисципліна/наука/мистецтво. В цьому воно споріднене зі словом «[фотографія](http://sum.in.ua/s/fotoghrafija)», що означає і спосіб, і сам відбиток ([світлину](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1068/4)), і салон/майстерню/установу.

Answer (score -1):

Спільнота шрифтових дизайнерів України включно з викладачами профільних навчальних закладів використовує термін "типографія" як усталений. Це консенсусне рішення, до якого в спільноті немає зауважень. Я є представником цієї спільноти і адміністратором групи "Шрифтороби" у ФБ.

Comment: Будь ласка, завжди надавайте джерела. Наразі ваша відповідь базується лише на вашому особистому авторитеті, який для більшості користувачів цього сайту не є відомим. Окрім того, посилання на авторитетні джерела убезпечують вашу відповідь від можливих заперечень і непотрібних дискусій у коментарях.